# How to get size of object with nested objects

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++17, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

Suppose I have various classes nested in one class and some are instantiated using pointers. I will try to provide a simple illustration. The goal is to find the total size of the object.

```cpp
class A {
    int x;
};

class B {
    float y;
};

class C {
    A a;
    std::vector<B> b;

    public:
    void some_func_to_handle_data_member_b()
    {
    // some logic inside to push_back and pop
    }
};

/* ... */

int main() {
    C c;
    // I need to find size of C object here here
    int size_of_c = sizeof(c); 

    // some more code goes here to copy everything into
    // another data structure from c after reserving the memory
    return 0;
}
```

`sizoef(c)` is not suitable for my application as the `sizeof()` returns `sizeof(int) + 24` which is the size of vector of type.
I would like to get the size of all the objects present inside the vector; something like:

```cpp
sizeof(b) * b.size()
```

`class B` is a third-party `class` and I cannot modify it.
All I can do is to make changes to `main()`.

I have tried writing sample programs to get around this, but could not get the expected result.

Comment: `sizeof( C );` is a compile time constant.  Changes to `b` (inserts etc) will have no effect on it's size which is fixed when the program is compiled.

Comment: `size_t C::totalSize() const { return sizeof(C) + sizeof(B) * b.size(); }`? You could use `b.capacity()` instead if you're interested in space allocated not space used. When you say "copy everything into another data structure" I worry you means something like `memcpy` and there is no contiguous blob of memory containing both the instance of C and the data in the vector. It might help if you explain a bit more what you're planning to do, and change the explanation as a comment to actual text outside the code block so it is easier to read.

Comment: Why would you even need to now the size in memory? Usually if beginning developers ask this, it is because they want to write memory to disk or network. This is called serialization and for C++ you might want to look it up (it is not trivial). In most cases it is more reliable to write code that doesn't make assumptions on memory layout.

Comment: Be aware that while sizeof(C) is a compile time constant, it can differ with compiler settings. MSVC, for example, differs between release and debug.

Comment: *" but could not get the expected result."*: what is the expected result? Please edit your question and provide concrete code examples for different scenarios what the *expected* output would be for them.